# how could I change osmdroid-android-4.1 to osmdroid-android-4.2 in existing android app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, osmdroid

I have an existing android app that uses the **osmdroid-android-4.1**.

Now I want to use the new **osmdroid-android-4.2**. Therefor I have copied the JAR files *(osm-android-4.2.jar and osmdroid-android--javadoc.jar)* into the folder "lib" and deleted the old physically JAR files.

Now my project contains errors.

Under "Fix project setup..." for the error "*ISafeCanvas cannot be resolved to a type*" it says:
Add archive 'osmdroid-android-4.1.jar'.

For example another errors:

- The method toMapPixelsProjected(int, int, Point) is undefined for the type Projection    PathOverlay2.java
- The method fromPixels(int, int) in the type Projection is not applicable for the arguments (float, float)

How could I resolve these problems?

Where can I have a look at the difference between the version *4.1* and *4.2*? How could I know, what I have to change in my app? How can I guarantee that the app is still working like before?

---

## edit #1:

*(right click - source - clean up ...)*
Under the radio button "use configured profiles I have selected my project.
*(click on next)*
Under "changes to be performed" I have selected all.
*(click on finish)*
But the errors still exists.

---

## edit #2:

I have changed these methods:
[renamed some projection methods](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/commit/ed5984a9e9741d1d698e983da863f37efefa5684)

- fromMecatorPixels   -> toPixelsFromMercator
- toPixelsProjected   -> toProjektedPixels
- toPixelsTranslated  -> toPixelsFromProjected
- toMapPixels         -> toPixels

But I can't find the new names of these methods:

1. fromPixels
2. fromPixelsToProjected

Comment: The changelog is there: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Changelog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed these methods *(old -> new)*:

- fromMecatorPixels -> toPixelsFromMercator
- toPixelsProjected -> toProjektedPixels
- toPixelsTranslated -> toPixelsFromProjected
- toMapPixels -> toPixels
- fromPixels(double, double) -> fromPixels((int)double, (int)double)
- Rect clipBounds = projection.fromPixelsToProjected(projection.getScreenRect()); -> Rect clipBounds = projection.getScreenRect();

---

Following links are useful to see the difference between the versions:

- [ChangeLog](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Changelog)
- [rename methods - commits](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/commit/ed5984a9e9741d1d698e983da863f37efefa5684)
- [guidelines](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/DeveloperGuidelines)
- [general commits](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/commits/master)

---

Until now the app opens the map with no errors. I hope I will have fixed all problems.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this. at your src package, right click on it and choose clean up from Source. then add your import again using the new library

Comment: *(right click - source - clean up ...)* Under the radio button "use configured profiles I have selected my project. *(click on next)* Under "changes to be performed" I have selected all. *(click on finish)* But the errors still exists. Have you an other idea?

Comment: have you import again the library after clean up for each source code ?

Comment: Should I have delete the library at first? Under *Java Biuld Path - Libraries* there are still there.

Comment: yes, and insert the new library.after that do clean up, check your each source for import new library.usually i do this for changing my library